# How to make a virtual machine forensics-proof - completely or to the maximum possible level?

Tags: encryption, disk-encryption, forensics, vmware, disk-image

I want to make a VMWare (VMWare is first preference but any alternative can be used as well) virtual machine completely digital forensics-proof. I am protecting against someone getting physical access to my computer when I am not there (I am gone for days or weeks). I turn off and power off the computer when I leave. Putting it under a physical lock is not possible.

How do you encrypt a VM so much or in such a way that nobody can retrieve anything from it? Is that even possible?

If so, how? what is that way?

If not, what is the maximum degree of anti-forensics I can use? How do I make it forensics-proof to the maximum level?

This question holds for Windows 10 host hosting Kali Linux VM **as well as** Kali Linux host hosting Windows 10 VM, **as well as** Windows 10 host hosting Windows 10 VM **as well as** Kali Linux host hosting Kali Linux VM.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming a guest Linux machine, you need to use full disk encryption with a [random key file for LUKS](https://www.cyberciti.biz/hardware/cryptsetup-add-enable-luks-disk-encryption-keyfile-linux/).

Basically you create a 4k file with random data and use it as the key for your LUKS device. In fact, you could use any file as the key, it being binary is enough.

If you don't store the key file together with the guest, it's not possible to decrypt the VM.

Comment: Thank you very much _but I also need it for Windows guest machine_ . Is that possible?

Comment: For Windows, you will use Bitlocker. And the same applies to the host system too: LUKS for Linux, Bitlocker for Windows.